# Rendering and best practices in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner in React, I have a question regarding rendering, which consists of I use useEfect to render the change in a variable, which is decorated in a useState

**Here are the statements:**

```
const CardRepo: React.FC<DadosCardRepo> = ({ Nome }) => {

const [nomeRepo, setNomeRepo] = useState(Nome);
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const [languages, setLanguages] = useState<Languages[]>([]);
```

This is a component, which receives an object with a Name, and sets this value Name in nameRepo

**Here are the two methods:**

```
useEffect(() => {
        getRepo(nomeRepo)
            .then(data => {
                setData(data);
            });
}, [nomeRepo]);

useEffect(() => {
        getLanguages(data['languages_url'])
            .then(data => {
                let total = 0;
                const languagesRef: Languages[] = [];
                Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
                    total += data[key];

                    languagesRef.push({ Nome: key, Porct: data[key] });
                });

                languagesRef.map((language, i, array) => {
                    setLanguages((oldValues) => [...oldValues, { Nome: language.Nome.toLowerCase(), Porct: +((language.Porct * 100) / total).toFixed(2) }]);
                });
            });
}, [data]);
```

Where the first useEfect I run when making a change to nomeRepo, and in this method, I make a request to the getRepo service

And the second one, when I change the date, and in this method, I make a request to the getLanguages ​​service, and do the processing of the response to make a list with it, where I assign languages.

**Here is the listing:**

```
{
  languages.map((el, i) => {
      return (
          <div className="progress-bar" id={el.Nome} key={i} style={{ width: el.Porct + '%' }}></div>
      );
  })
}
```

My question is related to rendering, I know that I will only be able to list something, if I use useEfect in the variable "languages", where I will be assigning values ​​and with the changes in the variable to render again, otherwise I couldn't.

But when I make any changes to the code, it renders only where it was changed, but it assigns the same values ​​that were assigned, for example: [1,2,3] => [1,2,3,1,2,3].
I tried to put setLanguages ​​([]), but it has the same behavior
I was wondering how to fix this and if it's a good practice to make calls and list that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, there is one bad practice where you create a derived state from props. `nomeRepo` comes from props `Nome`, you should avoid this derived states the most of you can. You better remove `nomeRepo` state and use only `Nome`.

your first use Effect becomes:

```
useEffect(() => {
        getRepo(Nome)
            .then(data => {
                setData(data);
            });
}, [Nome]);
```

you second `useEffect` has a `setState` triggered inside a map. That will trigger your setState multiple times, creating several rerenders. It's best to prepare your array of languages first, then call `setState` once.

Also, you should use `forEach` instead of `map` if you are not consuming the returned array, and only running some script on each element.

One thing to notice, is you are adding new languages to old ones. I assume that languages should be related `data['languages_url']` value, this way you wouldn't include the old languages to the setLanguages.

One thing you could consider is to keep your total values instead of percentages. you can store `total` into a variable with [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), that will depend on `languages`. And declare a your percentage function into a `utils` folder and import it as need it.

**refactored second useEffect:**

```
// calculate total value that gets memoized
const totalLangCount = useMemo(() => languages.reduce((total, val) => total + val.count , 0), [languages])

useEffect(() => {
  getLanguages(data['languages_url'])
      .then(data => {
          const languagesRef: Languages[] = [];
          Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
              // prepeare your languages properties
              const nome = key.toLowerCase();
              const count = data[key];

              languagesRef.push({ nome, count });
          });

          // avoid multiple setLanguages calls
          setLanguages(languagesRef)
      });
}, [data]);
```

**languages rendered:**

```
{
  languages.map((el, i) => {
      return (
          //  here we are using array's index as key, but it's best to use some unique key overall instead
          <div className="progress-bar" id={el.nome} key={i} style={{ width: percentage(el.count, total) }}></div>
      );
  })
}
```

**percentage function reusable:**

```
// utils percentage exported
export const percentage = (count, total) => ((count * 100) / total).toFixed(2) + '%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and help, it helped me a lot, I made all the changes you said and everything went well, in addition to learning